# Linux - bash script to find directories with conditions

Tags: linux, bash

I have many users under `/home`.
Each user has a certain amount of directories with big sizes.
I extracted the list of users created on the system into a text file without system users (uid below 1000). For example, root, ftp, and other system users are not in the usernames-list.txt

Is there a way we can allow `find` to search this usernames-list.txt list and access its `/home/` directories based on those 2 conditions can execute `rm -rf`?

condition 1: list files/directories with date modified/accessed older than 6 months.
condition 2: list files/directories that have the size of +50MB in size.

execute: `rm -f`

Comment: See `man find`, there are a lot of tests you can do with files. `for name in $(cat usernames-list.txt);do find /home/"$name" -type f -atime +180 -size +50M  -exec echo -f "{}" \;;done` If you are confortable with the results replace `echo` with `rm`

Comment: Thanks! so $name will be fetched by each name on the list right?

Comment: Yes, the loop will run `find` for each line in usernames.txt. I edited my comment, I wrote `-rf` but since find will search only for files there is no need of recursive option.

Comment: I nees it for directories too, should I add -f -d?

Comment: I don't know if `find` can do those tests with directories. What you want is delete just the directories that have such files or delete the whole `/home/user` directory?

Comment: No just the files and directories based on the conditions inside /home/user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72245/discussion-between-paulo-and-leblinux).

Answer (score 0):

This will list all directories with files with access time more than 180 days and size more than 50MB.

```
for name in $(cat usernames.txt); do
find /home/"$name" -type f -atime +180 -size +50M|sed 's/\/[^/]\+$//'|sort -u
done
```

To remove, I added `xargs` after `sort`.

In my own /home, I have some dirs with spaces and single quotes in the name (in my defense, some mp3 dirs:)). `xargs` printed a warning about and told me to add `-0` option, and to fix the null character I added delimiter option `-d'\n'`.

```
for name in $(cat usernames.txt); do
find /home/"$name" -type f -atime +180 -size +50M|sed 's/\/[^/]\+$//'|sort -u|xargs -0 -d'\n' -n1 -I{} echo -rf "{}"
done
```

If things seem ok for you, then you can replace `echo` with `rm` in the `xargs` command.

Maybe `rm` will print error messages because some parent directory will be removed before some subdirectory.

Comment: You're welcome. Be careful with that `rm -rf`, maybe the `/home/user` itself can appear in the list!! And remember the quota limits :)

Comment: Sure but as long as its accessing inside /home/$user i dont think it will rm -rf /home/user itself but will give it a try on testing systems :) again thank you for the help and time Paulo :)